# change rows values in relate to another row in django-models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm working on [leitner](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjl9ue875_5AhVBgM4BHXAwBXYQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLeitner_system&usg=AOvVaw1_RgRxiM47zUSG0GvL1EVd) flashcards system in django

the whole [leitner](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjl9ue875_5AhVBgM4BHXAwBXYQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLeitner_system&usg=AOvVaw1_RgRxiM47zUSG0GvL1EVd) sys is about BOXes order e.g `box1, box2 ,box3` ,so when u solve a card in box1 it gets moved backward to box2 and vise versa ..

now, what if I want to change the order of a box? or even delete it? wouldn't be better to change the other boxes orders? e.g [<s>box1</s>, box2, box3] => [box1, box2]

so now you got the idea, here's the BOX model structure in django-models file:

```py
class Box(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    order = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    end_days = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    end_hours = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    end_minutes = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

now the big Question is , when some row('obj') deleted/order-changed how can I increment/decrement other rows ???!

and if u have better idea than what I'm trying to do please share it .

EDIT:  `isn't there any SQL way to do it ??!`

regards

Comment: isn't there any SQL way to do it ??!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the change order case, this is shall be running in a view or something, there you need to bring all the boxes and do the update like this

Example move 3 to be 2 and 2 to be 3

```
old_box_number = 3
new_box_number = 2
for box in Box.objects.all():
   if box.sequence < new_box_number: continue 
   if box.sequence == new_box_number:
         box.sequence= old_box_number
         box.save()
  elif box.sequence == old_box_number:
         box.sequence= new_box_number
         box.save()
```

For delete,do the similar but reduce higher box by one.

Comment: al-salamo alikom, I thought about that and actually I implement it but I thought there's a built-in method that i could use OR something more cool looking ("engeneery") haha

Comment: isn't there any SQL way to do it ??!

Comment: You can convert thrse 2 ifs to 2 update statements set seq = seq-1